# wordpress - How to noindex plugin folders, but not block them

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, seo, noindex

I've searched but haven't found quite what I need. What I'm trying to do is noindex a plugin folders. Google for some reason has indexed a bunch of urls like this for example: `/wp-content/plugins/LayerSlider/static/public`

All that pulls up is a "Index of" page, so I'd like to get that and urls like it noindexed. I don't want to just block them with the robots file though because after reading the following article, it seems like a bad idea: [WordPress robots.txt example for great SEO](https://yoast.com/wordpress-robots-txt-example/)

There's also this to backup why blocking any css and js is a bad idea: [Google Panda 4, and blocking your CSS & JS](https://yoast.com/google-panda-robots-css-js/)

There's no index file or anything like that, so I'm wondering if there's a way to get these noindexed. Perhaps the htaccess file?

Comment: This question is not on topic as defined in [the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). If you don't understand why, please ask on [meta] for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use .htaccess file to add `X-Robots-Tag` header.

For example create new .htaccess file inside plugins directory and put this code inside it will add the header to all the files inside the folder.

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set X-Robots-Tag "noindex, nofollow"
</IfModule>
```

Make sure you have the headers modules installed / active.

Comment: Ah ok, so I could just put it in /wp-content/plugins/ and it'll noindex everything, but not block any content correct?

Comment: yes. its only add the header `X-Robots-Tag` to noindex and nofollow.